# Why the mov instruction isn't executed correctly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, gdb, x86-64

I met a mistake while debugging my program, and I can't solve it even after reading asm code
[image]

Here's the image from GDB, before 0x4070a1, %rdx is 0x61b130, and this number should be moved to `-0x18(%rbp)`. However, after this instruction, I found `-0x18(%rbp)` became 0x61b7d0, and this made me feel confused.

Due to this problem, my program can't run properly, can anyone tell me the reason? Thanks!

C code:

```
E_enventry t = E_FunEntry(level,label,NULL,NULL); //t here is 0x61b130
S_enter(venv,S_Symbol("flush"), t);
......
void S_enter(S_table t, S_symbol sym, void *value) {
    //while value here is 0x61b7d0
    TAB_enter(t,sym,value);
}
```

Comment: How about you show your C code so we can see what's wrong with it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @dbush Thanks, I have added it in the question, but I think the C code is meaningless, It's so weird.

Comment: @T.Chen it doesn't seem that the code you provided is enough for us to be able to reproduce the problem. Could you please create a minimal example that actually reproduce the problem

Comment: @Pac0 I'm so sorry, I'll try to give out one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p/x $rdx` showing `0x61b130` makes no sense.  The stack frame thing showing the function-entry value of `value` matches what you see in memory with `x` after the store.

I think your GDB is buggy, but the thing it's showing wrong is probably the value for `$rdx`, because that's what's inconsistent with two other sources.  (And according to your comment, also inconsistent with `p/x $rdx` after the spill/reload).

Try a different version of gdb, or try using a different debugger (which isn't also a front-end for GDB).  e.g. try `lldb`.

---

After spilling/reloading all 3 args to/from the stack, it ends up making a function call to `TAB_enter` with the first 3 args the same, and the 4th arg = 2rd arg (`sym` in your C source)

Or maybe there is no 4th arg, and it was just using `%rcx` as a temporary instead of loading directly into `%rsi`, like it used `%rax`.

`gcc -O0` is extremely braindead, and only some of that is on purpose (spill / reload everything between C statements to support *modifying* variables in memory with a debugger, or even jumping between source lines.)

TL:DR: unsurprisingly, the asm you showed exactly implements the source you showed for `void S_enter(S_table t, S_symbol sym, void *value)`, no more and no less.

Comment: @T.Chen: do you have any signal handlers installed?  Or anything else that would modify your process's registers or memory asynchronously?  I've been looking at your gdb session and it doesn't make sense.  Can you reproduce this on different runs?  What value is reloaded back into `%rdx`?

Comment: No, there is only one thread and I didn't add any signal handler. The result is the same every time.

Comment: @T.Chen: is it possible your `gdb` is buggy?  Maybe try a different debugger, like `lldb`.  Note that the stack-frame info has `value = 0x61b7d0` even before it's stored to the stack, so it has the correct value of `%rdx` there.

Comment: Does `gdb` show the expected value in `%rdx` after the reload instruction?

Comment: before the instruction at 0x4070a5, the `value` shown by gdb is not 0x61b7d0, and it's the instruction mov made it. After reload the number to %rdx, %rdx was also change to 0x61b7d0

Comment: In fact, I call this function many times in my code, and every time the `value` is 0x61d7b0, no matter what number I give it

Comment: @T.Chen: I assume you checked with a printf or something, because it seems your version of gdb might be buggy.

Comment: You are right! The value seems correct when I check with printf. Maybe I should use another debugger. Thank you!